# Momentum conservation in ionization

Tags: momentum, ionization-energy

When an atom ionized by a photon, is the total momentum of the photon and the emitted electron conserved?

Answer (score 1):

Categorically: No.

Total momentum of the system is conserved, and that includes an atom/ion.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean that the electron can move in the opposite direction of the photon?

Comment: @AndreasValadakis section 8 https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1112/notes/photelec.pdf

Comment: Thank you once more! So it isn't strange to have a photoelectron moving in the opposite direction of the incident, absorbed photon.

Comment: @AndreasValadakis Not really, a classical scattering direction like $\vec z$ becomes, in quantum mechanics, $\vec r \cos{\theta} \f$ (a la spherical coordinates), so you'll see a lot of $ 1 + \cos{\theta} $ terms in scattering  cross sections (which goes to zero at 180 deg). Also: a massive atom can take a lot of momentum with little energy: $p^2/2M$.